# How to change the href inside of a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to change the href of the  in this code:

```
<div class ="amp-logo">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google"></a>
</div>
```

I tried to use this code:

```
<script>
let link = document.querySelector('.amp-logo').getElementsByTagName('a');
link.href = window.origin+'/blog';
<\script>
```

but my code is not working. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `getElementsByTagName` returns an array of objects. You could make it work like so:

```js
let link = document.querySelector('.amp-logo').getElementsByTagName('a');
link[0].href = window.origin+'/blog'; // see the [0] here
```

```html
<div class="amp-logo">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google">X</a>
</div>
```

But you can select the `<a>` element directly like so

```js
let link = document.querySelector('.amp-logo > a');
link.href = window.origin+'/blog';
```

```html
<div class="amp-logo">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google">X</a>
</div>
```

or you could also only use the `title` attribute selector like so

```js
let link = document.querySelector('[title="Google"]');
link.href = window.origin+'/blog';
```

```html
<div class="amp-logo">
    <a href="http://www.google.com" title="Google">X</a>
</div>
```

or a combination of both methods like

```
let link = document.querySelector('.amp-logo [title="Google"]');
```